# No release history available stops dependent modules download

Tags: drush

I am creating my first make file to retrieve a custom module 'CUSTOM_MODULE' from github and running into trouble getting the dependent modules to be installed.

Here is make file at the Drupal site to install the module:

```
api = 2
core = 7.x
projects[CUSTOM_MODULE][type] = "module"
projects[CUSTOM_MODULE][subdir] = contrib
projects[CUSTOM_MODULE][version] = 7.x-1.0
projects[CUSTOM_MODULE][download][type] = "git"
projects[CUSTOM_MODULE][download][url] = "http://github.com/to-git-repo.git"
projects[CUSTOM_MODULE][download][branch] = "master"
```

To Get the custom module

```
 drush make someMakeFile.build --no-core --contrib-destination=sites/all
```

This install the CUSTOM_MODULE in sites/all/modules/contrib, however. It doesn't install all the dependencies as specified in the CUSTOM module local make file:

```
api = 2
core = 7.x
projects[] = audiofield
projects[] = block
projects[] = blog
projects[] = comment
projects[] = context
projects[] = jw_player
projects[] = libraries
projects[] = strongarm
projects[] = taxonomy
projects[] = text
projects[] = uuid_features
projects[] = video
projects[] = video_presets
projects[] = views
projects[] = node
```

When run in debug mode(--debug)

```
    ...
Found makefile: designssquare_com_blog.make [40 sec, 6.69 MB]                                                                                                                [ok]
Downloading release history from http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/audiofield/7.x [40.01 sec, 6.73 MB]                                                                  [notice]
/Users/maxit/.drush/cache/download/http---updates.drupal.org-release-history-audiofield-7.x retrieved from cache. [40.01 sec, 6.74 MB]                                          [notice]
Downloading release history from http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/block/7.x [40.06 sec, 6.74 MB]                                                                       [notice]
/Users/maxit/.drush/cache/download/http---updates.drupal.org-release-history-block-7.x retrieved from cache. [40.06 sec, 6.75 MB]                                               [notice]
No release history available for block 7.x
Returned from hook drush_make_process [40.06 sec, 6.7 MB]                                                                                                                        [debug]
Command dispatch complete
    ...
```

From the first line, it is processing the local CUSTOM_MODULE make file, however. It stops on second dependent module - 'block' and doesn't continue with the rest of the modules? While i would remove 'block' module as dependent (since it is part of core), my desired behavior would be it continue with the rest of the dependent module downloads, so the deployment completes with rest of the modules downloading.  How I would specify such a behavior? Thank You

p.s. Drupal 7.x, Drush Master, Mac

Comment: In a makefile you specify *projects* to download. `block`is not a project but a module part of drupal core. Same for `comment`or `node`. Simply remove them from the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

As per [@jonhattan](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99065/no-release-history-available-stops-dependent-modules-download#comment143232_99065) comment:

You need to specify projects to download in your makefile as `block` is not a project, but a module part of Drupal core. Same for `comment` or `node`. Simply remove them from the makefile.